# Why are there missing values in the American National Standards Institute (ANSI) Codes for States

Tags: geocoding

On the US Census Website there is a list of [American National Standards Institute (ANSI) Codes for States, the District of Columbia, Puerto Rico, and the Island Insular Areas of the United States](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/ansi_statetables.html)?

The first three rows of the table read:

```
Alabama         01    AL
Alaska          02    AK
Arizona         04    AZ
...
Wyoming         56    WY
```

There are other holes as well.

What happened to code #3?

Comment: American Samoa at a guess?

Comment: If this is open data your question may be suitable for the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: It's actually a question about geocoding and the ANSI/FIPS codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the wikipedia page: 
...certain numeric codes "are reserved for possible future use in identifying American Samoa (03), Canal Zone (07), Guam (14), Puerto Rico (43), and Virgin Islands (52)"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standard_state_code